# Table styling different in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

Have a contact form that I have some options to check for contact times and methods.  I had it styled correctly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.  The labels where to the left of the radio option and they were all lined up.

I have since run into the issue where the chrome style has broken and I cannot figure out what is going on as the Firefox and Safari CSS work perfectly. The page is [cbasphaltmaintenance.com](http://www.cbasphaltmaintenance.com/resident.php)

```
    <table id="contactOptionTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <h1>Prefered contact method:</h1>
                </td>    
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="home" name="contact_Method" class="contactRadioClass"/>
                <label for="home">Home</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="mobile" name="contact_Method" class="contactRadioClass" />
                <label for="home">Mobile</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="email" name="contact_Method" class="contactRadioClass" />
                <label for="home">Email</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <h1>Prefered contact time:</h1>
                </td>    
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="morning" name="contact_Time" class="contactRadioClass"/>
                <label for="home">Morning</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="afternoon" name="contact_Time" class="contactRadioClass" />
                <label for="home">Afternoon</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" value="night" name="contact_Time" class="contactRadioClass" />
                <label for="home">Evening</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Here is the css that works in safari and firefox

```
    #contactOptionTable{
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 14%;
 }

    .contactRadioClass{
    margin-top:10px;
    }
```

I don't know what is going on here but it is bugging me.  I appreciate all of the help.  As you may see I'm  a little wet behind the ears.

Comment: The link to the PHP file isn't working. Have you tried clearing your cache in Chrome? Are you sure your is CSS is actually being applied?

Comment: Yea I have cleared the cache and can move the table but for some reason the alignment is off and I can't figure out how to line everything backup.

Comment: Link should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class in your CSS.

```
#contactOptionTable input
{
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  thank you for the help.  I still have some hair left on my head

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce `margin-left: 5%` and add `width : 100%` to `#contactOptionTable`.

However I suggest you not to use table structure here, it would be better if you create it using `div's`

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked as well.  I was thinking about using divs and may still just for ease of use.  Thank you again